# Class with separated header: can see only initialization value of member variable

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I have a Test class defined in its own header, test.h, that is included on main.cpp file. Basically this is the situation:

**test.h**

```
class Test
{
    ...
    ...
    ...

public:
    long foo;
};
```

**test.cpp**

```
// Constructor
Test::Test()
{
    foo = 0
}

void Test::someMethod()
{
    // Here foo variable is changed
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Test testObject;
    ...
    // Do something with testObject
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

During debug on Visual Studio 2017 if I stop the execution inside main's code I can't see tha actual value of foo, I see its initialization value:

```
testObject.foo --> 0
```

Why this happens? If I stop the execution inside class I see its actual value.

**EDIT**

I found the problem. In main() I added a separated thread that launches Test::someMethod(). When I stop the execution inside main I can't see local thread's variable of testObject.

Is there a way to see a thread's local variables?

Comment: Did you try printing out the value? Like using `cout << testObject.foo`

Comment: Yes, it prints 0

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In main() I added a separated thread that launches Test::someMethod(). When I stop the execution inside main() I can't see local thread's variable of testObject